# (gdb) no symbol in current context when printing an exception object

Tags: c++, gdb

my program is expected to hit line 50 (catch clause) and I want to debug the exception object using gdb.

```
// main.cpp

try {
  ...
} catch (std::exception& ex) { // line 50
  ...
}
```

```
(gdb) b main.cpp:50
```

The program hit line 50 but when printing out `ex` object gives the following error:

```
(gdb) p ex
No symbol "ex" in current context.

(gdb) p ex.what()
No symbol "ex" in current context.
```

It let me print other variables but not `ex`. How can I print the variable?

Comment: Is the behavior the same if you put the breakpoint on the following line (inside the block)?

Comment: Thanks. I set a breakpoint on the next line, then now it works!